# Delete from association table that have primary composite key

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem when I want to delete from an association table that has a composite key and an extra column.

the association table is represented by an Entity that has two Object, **Collaborator** and **Competence**, with a relation *@ManyToOne*. On the other side, I have relation *@OneToMany* with **CollaboratorCompetence** *Entity* which has a ***composite key*** (collaborator_id, competence_id).

When I execute this *query* to delete a row on the collaborators_competences table, it works.

> Query 1

```
DELETE FROM collaborators_competences WHERE (collaborator_id, competence_id)
                                                IN (SELECT collaborator_id, competence_id FROM collaborators_competences
                                                    JOIN collaborators c on collaborators_competences.collaborator_id = c.id
                                                JOIN competences c2 on collaborators_competences.competence_id = c2.id
                                                WHERE c.id = (SELECT collaborators.id FROM collaborators WHERE login = :collabLogin) AND c2.id = :competenceId)
```

> Query 2 (simplified)

```
DELETE FROM  collaborators_competences cc WHERE cc.collaborator_id = (SELECT collaborators.id FROM collaborators WHERE collaborators.login = :collabLogin)AND cc.competence_id = :competenceId
```

Now when I execute the same *query* by using the repository, I got an error *"Could not extract Resultset"*.

> Repository

```
public interface CollaboratorCompetenceRepository extends JpaRepository<CollaboratorCompetence, CollaboratorCompetenceId> {
    Optional<CollaboratorCompetence> findById(CollaboratorCompetenceId id);

//    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM CollaboratorCompetence " +
//        "WHERE CollaboratorCompetence.collaborator IN (SELECT Collaborator FROM Collaborator WHERE Collaborator.login = :collabLogin)" +
//        "AND CollaboratorCompetence.competence IN (SELECT COmpetence FROM Competence WHERE Competence.id = :competenceId)")
//    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM  collaborators_competences WHERE collaborator_id = 1128 AND competence_id = 2551", nativeQuery = true)
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM collaborators_competences WHERE (collaborator_id, competence_id)\n" +
        "                                                IN (SELECT collaborator_id, competence_id FROM collaborators_competences\n" +
        "                                                    JOIN collaborators c on collaborators_competences.collaborator_id = c.id\n" +
        "                                                JOIN competences c2 on collaborators_competences.competence_id = c2.id\n" +
        "                                                WHERE c.id = (SELECT collaborators.id FROM collaborators WHERE login = :collabLogin) AND c2.id = :competenceId)", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteByCollaboratorLoginAndCompetenceId(@Param("collabLogin") String login, @Param("competenceId") Long id);

    void deleteCollaboratorCompetenceById(CollaboratorCompetenceId id);
}
```

Even with spring data, hibernate execute only select query, and no delete query.

> CollaboratorCompetence Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "collaborators_competences")
public class CollaboratorCompetence {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CollaboratorCompetenceId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("collaboratorId")
    private Collaborator collaborator;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("competenceId")
    private Competence competence;

    @Column(name = "note")
    private Integer note;

    public CollaboratorCompetence() {
    }

    public CollaboratorCompetence(Collaborator collaborator, Competence competence, Integer note) {
        this.id = new CollaboratorCompetenceId(collaborator.getId(), competence.getId());
        this.collaborator = collaborator;
        this.competence = competence;
        this.note = note;
    }
```

> CollaboratorCompetenceId (Embedable class)

```
@Embeddable
public class CollaboratorCompetenceId implements Serializable {

    @JoinColumn(name = "competence_id", table = "collaborators_competences")
    private Long competenceId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "collaborator_id", table = "collaborators_competences")
    private Long collaboratorId;

    public CollaboratorCompetenceId() {
    }

    public CollaboratorCompetenceId(Long competenceId, Long collaboratorId) {
        this.competenceId = competenceId;
        this.collaboratorId = collaboratorId;
    }

    public Long getCompetenceId() {
        return competenceId;
    }

    public void setCompetenceId(Long competenceId) {
        this.competenceId = competenceId;
    }

    public Long getCollaboratorId() {
        return collaboratorId;
    }

    public void setCollaboratorId(Long collaboratorId) {
        this.collaboratorId = collaboratorId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CollaboratorCompetenceId that = (CollaboratorCompetenceId) o;
        return Objects.equals(competenceId, that.competenceId) &&
            Objects.equals(collaboratorId, that.collaboratorId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(competenceId, collaboratorId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CollaboratorCompetenceId{" +
            "competenceId=" + competenceId +
            ", collaboratorId=" + collaboratorId +
            '}';
    }
}
```

> Error stack :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2168)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1931)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2200)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1016)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:214)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:602)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 175 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Aucun résultat retourné par la requête.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:107)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 203 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you translate this line `Aucun résultat retourné par la requête.`?

Comment: No result returned by the query

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add annotation `@Modifying` to the Query.

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM collaborators_competences WHERE (collaborator_id, competence_id)\n" +
    "                                                IN (SELECT collaborator_id, competence_id FROM collaborators_competences\n" +
    "                                                    JOIN collaborators c on collaborators_competences.collaborator_id = c.id\n" +
    "                                                JOIN competences c2 on collaborators_competences.competence_id = c2.id\n" +
    "                                                WHERE c.id = (SELECT collaborators.id FROM collaborators WHERE login = :collabLogin) AND c2.id = :competenceId)", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteByCollaboratorLoginAndCompetenceId(@Param("collabLogin") String login, @Param("competenceId") Long id);




@Transactional
void deleteCollaboratorCompetenceById(CollaboratorCompetenceId id);
```

Use of `@Modifying`

As the annotation says, it is used for Modifying queries. Now, what are modifying queries.

- Modifying Queries are any query that **writes** some data to the entities i.e. modifying the **entities**. This includes Update and Delete queries.
- `@Modifying` should be used for custom queries in JPA repository using `@Query` annotation

**Note:** Sometimes you may get an exception as `RollBackException` at that time you need to handle the logic using `@Transactional` annotation. Just annotate your method or repository method signature with `@Transactional` when you get such exception.

Comment: Thank you Mansoor, can you explain when should I add it?
It works perfectly.

Comment: Yup, thank you very much, but when I try to delete with spring data by using this method : 
`@Modifying
void deleteCollaboratorCompetenceById(CollaboratorCompetenceId id);
`
It doesn't work, hibernate execute the only select requests
Do you know why?

Comment: Can you try removing @Modifying?

Comment: delete/update queries return int i.e. number of rows affected. Can you change the signature first. And then see the actual issue.

Comment: Firstly add `@Transactional`. If it doesn't work then there may not be any data associated with that ID.

Comment: I'd suggest to use @Query and avoid derived query as that will avoid `SELECT` before delete.

Comment: It doesn't work and on the console, there is an only select query and no delete that executed by hibernate.
But it perfectly works with the @Query